# Repeating images with the :after pseudo-elements

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I would like to put headlines in my site like this: http://cl.ly/0m3F0j392e0G1n0s0T34
What i'd ideally like to do is use text for the headline and then have a 10px by 10px gif repeat horizontally after it.

**EDIT:** I should add that I would like to use a textured background so I can't set any solid colours to the h2 element.

I have been able to add in the gif after the headline but I can't get it to repeat, even if i add repeat-x. Here's the code i used:

```
h2:after {
content: 'url(img/imagehere.gif) repeat-x';
}
```

Are there any workarounds for this or any alternate methods? I'd rather not resort to slicing the entire headline as an image. I've thought about floating the headline to the left then floating an empty div to the right with the gif as a repeating background image but I figure this is what the :after pseudo-element is for, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little hacky and will involve adding `overflow-x:hidden;` to the parent element, but should do the trick:

```
h2 {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 10px;
    float: left;
    }
h2::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    right: 9999px;
    background: url(image.gif);
    height: 10px;
    width: 9999px;
    }
```

Comment: FYI note the difference in notation between _pseudo-elements_ and _pseudo-classes_ in [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#gen-content)

Comment: FYI note the difference between browser compatibility and CSS3 :P

Answer (score 0):

You can set any attributes to your after pseudo element. What I would do it set the content to "" (empty) and then set a width and height to the pseudo element. You can set the background to the repeated gif as normal then.

```
h2:after {
  content: "";
  height:20px;
  width:400px;
  background:url('img/imagehere.gif') repeat-x top left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried that and it seems logical but doesn't worth for whatever reason. I've set it up on JSfiddle to show you: http://jsfiddle.net/PMc4S/

Answer (score 0):

When you use `content:url()` pressed class create an `img` element. You need to use `background` in this case. Like what Erik said.

But if size of your text in heading is not known (aka dynamic content) then pseudo element is not a good work around. You can use a markup like this:

```
<h1><span>your text content</span></h1>
```

And then add the repetitive background to `h`

```
h1{ background:'url(img/imagehere.gif) repeat-x';}
```

To hide background in part that text apears make the `span`'s background a solid color

```
span{background:white}
```

Update:

if you have a background image under your `h1`, then you can do this:

Same HTML: `<h1><span>your text content</span></h1>`

CSS:

say your `body` have a background image:

```
body{background-image:(foo)}
```

then you want `bar` to be your image to repeat after the heading. You should do this:

```
h1{background:url(bar)}
```

And add same background your `body` have to the `span` containing your text:

```
h1 span{background-image:(foo)}
```

This would solve your problem. Look at this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fCyp/1/)** to see in action. It's not depended on your text size or anything else.

Note: if you are using an `span` then you should make it `dispaly:inline-block`

Update:

Based on your request I rethink on this. I used `tables` this time. Code without explanation:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><h1>Heading</h1></td>
            <td class="pattern"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
body{background:url(foo)}
table, tbody, tr{width:100%;}
.pattern{background:url(bar); width:100%;}
```

**[See in action<](http://jsfiddle.net/2fCyp/2/)**

Comment: Hi, good workaround! Trouble is these elements are on top of a textured background (sorry, I didn't state this in the original post) so a solid colour will look a bit odd

Comment: Hi, yea that also a good fix. The problem I think i'll have is that the texture I would like to use is quite detaild (I'm thinking a blueprint) so the two background images might not match up. I flipped them on your fiddle to show you: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/RRwV9/)

Comment: OK, got it! See updates! (I hate tables too, but it's better than using JS for styling)

Comment: Mohsen you've been a massive help and I really appreciate you helping out! Looks like the CSS trick from Chris works a charm as well

Answer (score 0):

The answer above from Erik Hinton will work if you add "display:block" declaration, as below:

```
h2:after {
  content: "";
  display:block;
  height:20px;
  width:400px;
  background:url('img/imagehere.gif') repeat-x top left;
}
```